RegEx Javascript: How to replace all instances of "non-white space character + CR + LF" with, "white space character + CR + LF"
I'm passing a string with jQuery, but it throws an Invalid or unexpected token error anytime there's a CR+LF without a leading white space in front of it.
I'm trying to use the js function replaceAll() to fix these instances before passing the string, but I can't seem to find the right syntax.
When I use replaceAll(new RegExp(/\S+[\r\n]/g), " \r\n");, it replaces the \S string, when I just want to replace the \r\n with a space + \r\n AFTER the \S.
For example, I want:
This is the end
of the line

To become (underscore symbolizes a space character):
This is the end_
of the line

It's important that if a line already ends with a space + CRLF, that we don't add an additional space character.
UPDATE
Okay, I actually got a working regular expression:
replaceAll(new RegExp(/(?<=\S)[\r\n]/g), " \r\n")

Unfortunately jQuery still throws a syntax error, HOWEVER, if I manually type the space character in front of the CRLF before submitting, I don't get a syntax error.  Very confused.

You could match \S(?=[\r\n]) and replace with $&_ See https://regex101.com/r/PQWQub/1

I would use a look behind assertion, but also an end-of-line assertion: replaceAll(/(?<=\S)$/gm, " ");. Note that you don't need to call new RegExp when you already have a regex literal.

BTW, it is not jQuery that throws a syntax error. There is no jQuery specific code in your question.

Side note: don't use the regexp constructor + literal: new RegExp(/(?<=\S)[\r\n]/g) use either one or the other. Using both doesn't make sense, since the constructor will clone the regex which is passed in as a literal.

It turns out it was the \r causing the syntax error, so now I'm just using:
replaceAll(new RegExp(/(?<=\S)[\r\n]/g), " \n");

If you must replace the match for [\r\n] with a newline \n as you state in your answer, you could also use a capture group denoted as $1 to capture what you need and match the [\r\n]
In the replacement you use the capture group 1 value followed by a newline.
(\S)[\r\n]

See a regex demo.
For example, still using the _ in the replacement to symbolize a space character:


const regex = /(\S)[\r\n]/g;
const str = `This is the end
of the line`;
const result = str.replace(regex, `$1_\n`);

console.log(result);




I tried txt.replace(/ *$/mg," ") at first, but it would have changed "b \n" into "b  \n" (by adding another blank to it). So, in the end I went for two replace operations:

remove all blanks at the end of each line
add a single blank at the end of each line


const txt="a\nb \nc  \nd   \ne f g\nh";
console.log("before:",JSON.stringify(txt));

console.log("after:",JSON.stringify(txt.replace(/ *$/mg,"").replace(/$/mg," ")));




